# WebLogic NoClassDefFoundError even with <prefered-application-packages>

Tags: java, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting NoClassDefFoundError when running my code in QA server, but localy (using Eclipse) it runs just fine.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat
```

I have faced this issue in another project which I fixed using the `<wls:prefer-application-packages>` property. I checked the EAR file and the Apache CSV .jar is present in the build, and I did set the prefered application packages properly as well.

Here is my `weblogic-application.xml`. Only `org.apache.*` should be enough but it was not working so I added the complete Apache CSV package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
    xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd">

    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.*</wls:package-name>
        <wls:package-name>org.apache.commons.csv.*</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>

    <wls:prefer-application-resources>
        <wls:resource-name>org.apache.*</wls:resource-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-resources>

</wls:weblogic-application>
```

My EAR POM declares the compile dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

And the EJB module POM uses it as provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

To be sure I checked the EAR build file generated by Maven, which we deploy into QA, and the Apache CSV jar is bundled inside de EAR file:

[image]

And the weblogic-application.xml file is also present under META-INF folder in the EAR file:

[image]

Even so I am getting `NoClassDefFoundError`. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd guess that it's not packaged properly in the EAR.

Comment: @duffymo I also think so, but all seems ok looking at it.

Comment: I don't know what the latest recommendation is for packaging.  I use Spring, not EJB, so it's usually a WAR when I have to deploy on JBOSS.   When that's the case I see a WEB-INF/lib folder with JARs in it.  Is that what you have?

Comment: @duffymo solved it.

Comment: Well done.  That's a good solution for you and someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `<defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>` that tells Maven to create the `application.xml` properly.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
        <version>5</version>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And the `application.xml` is created with that information:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" version="5">
  <!-- modules -->
  <library-directory>lib</library-directory>
</application>
```